# Dados do deploy que não podem ir para o github

Tags: git, github

Bom dia,

Eu tenho 1 projeto, que está em desenvolvimento e estou usando o github na fase de desenvolvimento. Porém arquivos de configuração que possuem senha, eu n mando pro github haha.

Qnd eu fizer o ultimo commit e logo em seguida o deploy para o servidor de aplicação irão os arquivos de config com senha e tudo +.

Caso eu queira fazer uma nova implementação e precise usar o github novamente, esse ultimo commit com os arquivos de config com senha e tudo + irão junto ao proximo push no github.

Qual seria a melhor prática nessa situação? Para que o commit que foi feito especificamente para o deploy, não va para o github e exponha senhas e etc.

Comment: Creio que isso já foi respondido aqui no site, seria legal se alguém achasse o link. Além da opção do ignore para certos arquivos, a própria rede que mantem o SOpt tem uma solução que criptografa certos arquivos à sua escolha, e esta solução está disponivel no github

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox